# Chessboard image tag changed into images

Tags: javascript, jquery, chessboard.js

I'm working in chessboard.js in my project, but when i'm rendering chessboard into my project , it's convert `<img />` tag into `<images />`

Please take a look at the image.. 
[image]
what can i do now ???

Here the code screen shot. 
[image]

Comment: Please read [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly, otherwise this is impossible to answer.

Comment: ok bro... @Tijmen

Comment: why would it convert an img tag to an images tag? It seems more pertinent to solve that problem than to figure out how to replace the nodes after they're created.

Comment: yes i think so bro, please let me know if you have different thought @zfrisch

Comment: @kousheralampranto what is the code that you're using to create them? I'm looking at the documentation and from the source code I can see that it has img tags

Comment: bro i update the question please take a look ...

Comment: @kousheralampranto I can't replicate the issue. Every example I've found shows "img" tags, not "images", including the documentation. I'm inclined to believe it's either something in your project that's being externally added from another source or something you've unassumingly added yourself. Can you create some example code for us so we have something tangible to work with? Otherwise I'm afraid we won't be able to "fix" the issue, just create a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('images').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceTag('<img>', true);
    });
  });
```

Comment: This simply puts a band aid on the problem without actually solving the root of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want replace a existing tag you can do this:

```
$('images').each(function(){
     $(this).replaceWith('<img>' + $(this).html() +'</img>')
});
```